# Can I release object in this way

Tags: objective-c

```
UILabel *labelTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 80, 80, 50)];
[self.view addSubView:labelTitle];
[labelTitle release];
```

or

```
UILabel *labelTitle = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 80, 80, 50)] autorelease];
[self.view addSubView:labelTitle];
```

Thanks!

Comment: First way is cleaner and easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the first way.  The second basically delays the release to a later time. This tends to use more resources in some situations since unused memory isn't being returned as soon as it could be.

---

in fact, use allocWithZone:NULL instead of alloc save a method call.